# Best way to add functionality to built-in types

Tags: java, oop

I wonder what is the best way in terms of strict OOP to add functionality to built-in types like Strings or integers or more complex objects (in my case the BitSet class).

To be more specific - I got two scenarios:

1. Adding a md5 hashing method to the String object
2. Adding conversion methods (like fromByteArray() or toInteger()) to the BitSet class.

Now I wonder what the best practices for implementing this would be.

I could e.g. create a new Class "BitSetEx" extending from BitSet and add my methods. But I don't like the idea since this new class would need describing name and "BitSetWithConversionMethods" sound really silly.

Now I could write a class consisting only of static methods doing the conversions.

Well I got a lot of ideas but I wan't to know what would be the "best" in sense of OOP.

So could someone answer me this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches here:

Firstly, you could come up with a better name for the `extends BitSet` class. No, `BitsetWithConversionMethods` isn't a good name, but maybe something like `ConvertibleBitSet` is. Does that convey the intent and usage of the class? If so, it's a good name. Likewise you might have a `HashableString` (bearing in mind that you can't extend `String`, as Anthony points out in another answer). This approach of naming child classes with `XableY` (or `XingY`, like `BufferingPort` or `SigningEmailSender`) can sometimes be a useful one to describe the addition of new behaviour.

That said, I think there's a fair hint in your problem (not being able to find a name) that maybe this isn't a good design decision, and it's trying to do too much. It is generally a good design principle that a class should "do one thing". Obviously, depending on the level of abstraction, that can be stretched to include anything, but it's worth thinking about: do 'manipulating the set/unset state of a number of bits' and 'convert a bit pattern to another format' count as one thing? I'd argue that (especially with the hint that you're having a hard time coming up with a name) they're probably two different responsibilities. If so, having two classes will end up being cleaner, easier to maintain (another rule is that 'a class should have one reason to change'; one class to both manipulate + convert has at least 2 reasons to change), easier to test in isolation, etc.

So without knowing your design, I would suggest maybe two classes; in the `BitSet` example, have both a `BitSet` and (say) a `BitSetConverter` which is responsible for the conversion. If you wanted to get really fancy, perhaps even:

```
interface BitSetConverter<T> {
 T convert(BitSet in);
 BitSet parse(T in);
}
```

then you might have:

```
BitSetConverter<Integer> intConverter = ...;
Integer i = intConverter.convert(myBitSet);
BitSet new = intConverter.parse(12345);
```

which really isolates your changes, makes each different converter testable, etc.

(Of course, once you do that, you might like to look at [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and consider using a [Function](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html), e.g. a `Function<BitSet, Integer>` for one case, and `Function<Integer, BitSet>` for the other. Then you gain a whole ecosystem of `Function`-supporting code which may be useful)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the extending class. That is actually what you are doing, extending the current class with some extra methods.

As for the name: you should not name at for the new features, as you might add more later on. It is your extended BitSet class, so `BitSetEx` allready sounds better then the `BitSetWithConversionMethods` you propose.

You don't want to write a class with the static methods, this is like procedural programming in an OOP environment, and is considered wrong. You have an object that has certain methods (like the `fromByteArray()` you want to make) so you want those methods to be in that class. Extending is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  As nanne pointed out, subclass is an option.  But only sometimes.  Strings are declared final, so you cannot create a subclass.  You have at least 2 other options:

1) Use 'encapsulation', i.e. create a class MyString which has a String on which it operates (as opposed to extending String, which you cannot do).  Basically a wrapper around the String that adds your functionality.

2) Create a utility/helper, i.e. a class with only static methods that operate on Strings.  So something like

```
class OurStringUtil {
....
    public static int getMd5Hash(String string) {...}
....

}
```

Take a look at the [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) stuff, it follows this approach; it's wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

"Best way" is kinda subjective. And keep in mind that String is a final class, so you can't extend it. 
Two possible approaches are writing wrappers such as `StringWrapper(String)` with your extra methods, or some kind of `StringUtils` class full of static methods (since Java 5, static methods can be imported if you wan't to use the util class directly).